# Machine Learning, What are the common techniques for feature engineering and presenting the model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, visualization

I am having a ML language identification project (Python) that requires a multi-class classification model with high dimension feature input.

Currently, all I can do to improve accuracy is through trail-and-error. Mindlessly combining available feature extraction algorithms and available ML models and see if I get lucky.

I am asking if there is a commonly accepted workflow that find a ML solution systematically.

This thought might be naive, but I am thinking if I can somehow visualize those high dimension data and the decision boundaries of my model. Hopefully this visualization can help me to do some tuning. In MATLAB, after training, I can choose any two features among all features and MATLAB will give a decision boundary accordingly. Can I do this in Python?

Also, I am looking for some types of graphs that I can use in the presentation to introduce my model and features. What are the most common graphs used in the field?

Thank you

Comment: "I am asking if there is a commonly accepted workflow that find a ML solution systematically." No, there isn't. If there were, you could be replaced by a program. Maybe some day soon, but not yet.

Comment: Automate the automation, although I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga it depends on your problem. The whole objective of deep learning is the automation of feature extraction and with certain hyper parameter tuning libraries that use not just Grid-Search, but are dealt with as a optimization problem as well, you could say there is a method for automation. However your question aims for visualising high dimensional data. There are a lot of dimensionality reduction techniques that map high dimensional data e.g. t-SNE.

Comment: @Zephro How can I plot the decision boundary on the dimensional reduced data? Should I train a classifier based on the dimensional reduced data?

Comment: @YiShen I've never done it before, but how to derive decision boundaries also depends on the method you use. If you are able do determine the boundaries in high dimensional space you should be able to transform them with the same methods like t-SNE into the lower dimensional space. But I am guessing here. I only believe that this would not add a lot of value to your analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature engineering is more of art than technique. That might require domain knowledge or you could try adding, subtracting, dividing and multiplying different columns to make features out of it and check if it adds value to the model. If you are using Linear Regression then the adjusted R-squared value must increase or in the Tree models, you can see the feature importance, etc.